# Firebase Cloud Functions Http Request - VALIDATE USER

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm building a web app where I want to call a cloud function from the client to edit a part of the database that shouldn't be accessible to the user.

The user should only be able to edit the hidden part of the database that is theirs.

I want to use an HTTP request trigger (as it seems the most practical), but I need to be able to have the client somehow prove through either a parameter or some other method that they are a certain user.

Is this possible, if so what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable). Note that firebase.auth() provides user/client authentication.  So, the Firebase Functions will be talking to the data store via a service account.

> Callable functions are similar to other HTTP functions, with these
>   additional features:
>
> - With callables, Firebase Authentication and FCM tokens, when available, are automatically included in requests.
> - The functions.https.onCall trigger automatically deserializes the request body and validates auth tokens.